# Why does transform.Find() fail when I edit my script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project in Unity where in the **Awake()** function, my Engine.cs script uses GameObject.Find() to access PlayerHUD, then uses transform.Find() to access its child WeaponButtonsUI, from which I use GetComponent() to access its script UIPanel.

UIPanel has two completely blank functions called Attach() and Detach(). Adding the call to Attach() in **public override Tank owner** works fine, but when I add the Detach() function call, all of my Find() calls fail at runtime and not a single field is found. However, all of my debug statements indicate that the fields are not null, despite them visibly being null in the inspector. I'm really stumped, any help would seriously be appreciated.

```
public GameObject playerHUD; 
public GameObject weaponButtonsUI;
public UIPanel wScript;

protected override void Awake()
    {
        playerHUD = GameObject.Find("PlayerHUD"); 
        if (playerHUD != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("PlayerHUD found");

            weaponButtonsUI = playerHUD.transform.Find("WeaponButtonsUI").gameObject;
            if (weaponButtonsUI != null) 
            { 
                wScript = weaponButtonsUI.GetComponent<UIPanel>(); 
                Debug.Log("Found weps"); 
            }
            else { Debug.Log("WeaponButtonsUI not found"); }
        }
    }

public override Tank owner
    {
        set
        {
            if (currentOwner == value && currentOwner != null) { return; }
            var newOwner = value;
            Tank oldOwner = currentOwner;
            if (currentOwner == null)
            {
             
            }
            else
            {
                currentOwner.parts.Remove(this);
                currentOwner.invalidate();
                currentOwner.controlOwner = null;
                
            }
            if (newOwner == null) //Engine removed from Tread
            {
                PartTools.addPhysics(gameObject);
                transform.SetParent(null, true);
                currentOwner = newOwner;

                if (audioManager != null) { loopSource.Stop(); Debug.Log( "STOP"); }
                else { Debug.Log("AudioManager is missing"); }
                Debug.Log("Engine room removed");

                //DISABLE (PROBLEM CODE)
                wScript.Detach();
                //DISABLE (PROBLEM CODE)
            }
            else //Engine attached to Tread
            {
                PartTools.removePhysics(gameObject);
                newOwner.parts.Add(this);         //add to newowner list
                currentOwner = newOwner;                     //set currentowner
                newOwner.invalidate();                         //apply change to newowner
                newOwner.controlOwner = controller;
                transform.SetParent(newOwner.transform, true);//set transform parent
                Debug.Log("Engine room attached");

                //ENABLE
                wScript.Attach();
                
            }
            ownerChangeEvent.Invoke(oldOwner, newOwner);
            //if(onOwnerChanged!=null)
            //onOwnerChanged(oldOwner, newOwner);
        }
        get{return currentOwner;}
    }
```

Comment: why protected overrdes? and public overrides? this is not normal

Comment: This isn't all my code, I'm just trying to add a couple function calls to Engine.cs, which was written by someone else.

Comment: In general use `Awake` to initialize internal variables and `Start` to initialize things that depend on other objects.

Comment: Just made this change, didn't fix my issue but that's good to know for the future, thanks.

Comment: when you debug it, what does it show?

Comment: @BugFinder the `protected override` is very valid. In particular for Unity's messages it makes sense :) They should not be `public` as they are called by Unity itself - and the other one is `public` as it is called from the outside - no problem there imho

Comment: @OP I would never use `Find` though. hard coded strings are horrible to maintain - hierarchies and names can easily change. Instead rather have a proper component attached to your root `GameObject` that knows and provides all other relevant sub objects and components - or even doesn't expose them at all but rather methods that do what you want to do with those child references. And that one controller reference you can inject when you spawn your object - the thing that is responsible for calling `Instantiate` can also handle the injection of dependencies - some `Initialize` method for instance

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,, I'd been told it was good practice to use Find() statements where possible to limit the amount of drag-and-drop required in the inspector, but I agree it makes things difficult when object or script names change. I'll try a full rewrite and see how things go.